# How can I remove `OnClickListeners` from Recycled Views?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am using `RecyclerViews` in my app project and apparently when a `View` is recycled, they keep their listeners.

I tried to remove listeners in the method `onViewRecycled()`

```
@Override
public void onViewRecycled(MyViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
    holder.imageId.setOnClickListener(null);
}
```

but didn't work.

Any more idea...?

Comment: Where are you setting the `OnClickListener` initially? Any `View` properties that change depending on position should be set in the `onBindViewHolder()` method.

Comment: @MikeM. i'm setting in the onBindViewHolder() method.

Comment: Well, that's probably why your `View` has an `OnClickListener` again. After it's recycled, it's going to be passed into `onBindViewHolder()` to ready it for use again. If you're unconditionally setting a listener on it in that method, that would be why.

Answer (score 0):

Set onclicklisteners in your view holder. This way listeners will be set only once. You'll get adapter position in viewholder.